# Birth-death processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am still a bit confused with how a Markov chain with an absorption state transitions from  one state to another, given it's a birth-death process.

Car Service.   A service is carried out sequentially as follows:  T(tune-up), A(air-conditioning), B(brakes).  The mean 
service times are respectively 1,2,3 hours. Assume the services are independent and exponentially distributed.  If  X(t) denotes
the state of service at time t then it can be modeled by a birth-death process on states {1,2,3,4} where 4 corresponds to the 
absorbing state (i.e., all three services 1-T, 2-A, 3-B have been completed and therefore the transition rate to leave 4 is 0).
Then the transition rate matrix has the form

$\begin{matrix}
  -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & -1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & -1/3 & 1/3\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{matrix}$

What is the probability that 5 hours after the service started the car is still in the brake repair stage?

I already exponentiated the matrix for time $t = 1$:

$P = \begin{matrix}
  0.367879 & 0.477302 & 0.137026 & 0.017792\\
  0 & 0.606531 & 0.330002 & 0.0634674\\
  0 & 0 & .716531 & 0.283469\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{matrix}$

Then when $t = 5$, I think what I'm looking for is $P_{1,3}^{5}$

$P^{5} = \begin{matrix}
  0.00673795 & 0.150694 & 0.367537 & 0.475031\\
  0 & 0.082085 & 0.320372 & 0.597543\\
  0 & 0 & 0.188876 & 0.811124\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{matrix}$

At least this is the conclusion I came to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transition matrix is wrong. Its row sums should all be zero and its off-diagonal entries should all be nonnegative. You should have

$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1/3 & 1/3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: No, This matrix has to be exponentiated i.e. $ e^{M} $ since the matrix is made up of exponentially distributed $ \lambda_{i} = $"birth" ~ Poisson process and $\mu_{i} =$ "death ~ Poisson process

Comment: Never mind, I see what you were getting at. I fixed my typo in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I still need a bit of help understanding the conditioning, i,e, if it time t the process is in state 1, what is the probability it is in state 3 by time 5. I think I know but I suppose I need confirmation.

Comment: The last row should still be all zeros; the $1$ in the bottom right comes from the identity term in the power series for the exponential. It is not in the generator itself. As for your question, I think you are asking for $(e^{(5-t)L})_{1,3}$, where $L$ is the matrix above. (Probably; given the problem, I wouldn't be surprised if you wanted the probability of being in $3$ or $4$ at time $5$.) If you have $e^M$ already then you can indeed simply raise this to a power as needed.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about the typos initially I corrected that one, too.